# Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

What is  the best way to implement the navigation drawer through multiple activities or with the help of fragments.Currently i am working with the help of multiple activities is this right way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by navigation drawer through multiple activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ActionBarSherlock Navigation Drawer. It will work with API level 8 also. So try [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/) and [this](https://github.com/tobykurien/SherlockNavigationDrawer) link. And you have to work with fragments rather than Activities.

Comment: can use appcompat for backward compatibility.

Comment: I am using Navigation Drawer by activities instead of fragments.I have created all my activities so do i have to change all those activities in fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Fragments for android. Its the best way. If you use Fragments you do not have to write the code for providing the functionality of Navigation. Its the most recommended way in android for navigation. Refer the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Navigation Drawer with Fragments is the most recommended approach. It provides lot of flexibility rather than activity. I advise you to implement with Fragments. If you wanna do in  standard approach the Fragments are the right and the most correct way.
Check the Design Specifications.

Comment: I am using Navigation Drawer by activities instead of fragments.I have created all my activities so do i have to change all those activities in fragments.

Comment: @Prathamesh Your MainActivity will contain the navigation Drawer. The Fragments will be the page/form that is generated when u will click in the options it will be replaced by the existing page.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the problem you are facing and I recommend you to check out [this article I've written about the Nav Drawer navigation](https://medium.com/android-news/material-design-navigation-drawer-iii-navigating-c30dde2132cc).

When you have clear on which places you are showing the Drawer then the best way to implement it is using the [Android Support Design Library](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwjGmubmyfPGAhXJWBQKHZboDOo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandroid-developers.blogspot.com%2F2015%2F05%2Fandroid-design-support-library.html&ei=xxWyVYabN8mxUZbRs9AO&usg=AFQjCNGnNseCVodUZHtqZAlNQL7VAEuQQA&sig2=HD_WP6wTVenyZR1y_n0RPw&bvm=bv.98476267,d.d24).

When you have different activities where you are showing the Drawer (this could be different hierarchy levels in your app) you'll have to create/reuse a new Drawer on that activity that knows on which activity is in to show as selected that entry on the Drawer.

I don't know if that is exactly your question but hope so.